# How to reproject all geometries columns in a PostGIS schema

Tags: postgis, postgresql, coordinate-system

Is there's a way to reproject all geometries columns of a postgis schema given the same source SRID to the same destination SRID?
Exemple :
*schema.table1* has 2 geometries columns *geom* and *geom2* with the same SRID 900913
*schema.table2* has 2 geometries columns *geom* and *geom2* with the same SRID 900913
etc..
I want to project all those columns in SRID 2154.
I tought there's could be a simple way by using the public.geometry_columns view but I don't know how.

Comment: Interested to know if you have tried out my answer, have an issue with it, etc?

Answer (score 6):

You can do this using a [Postgres DO block](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-do.html), essentially an anonymous function that you just run once from a psql prompt. Something along these lines:

```
DO $$declare r record; 
  BEGIN 
    FOR r in SELECT srid as srs, f_table_name as name, f_geometry_column as geom
         FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_schema = 'schema_name'
    LOOP
       RAISE NOTICE 'updating table: %, geom column: %, with srid: %', r.name, r.geom, r.srs;
       PERFORM UpdateGeometrySRID(r.name, r.geom, 2154); 
       EXECUTE FORMAT ('UPDATE %I set %I = ST_Transform(%I, 2154)', r.name,  r.geom, r.geom);
    END LOOP;
END$$;
```

This uses [UpdateGeometrySRID](http://postgis.org/docs/UpdateGeometrySRID.html) to update the meta data and [ST_Transform](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Transform.html) to transform the geometries. You have to use `Perform` within an anonymous block like this, as you are not returning anything from the select and `execute format` as you have dynamic table names.

Naturally, you can add more to the `WHERE` clause, as you might not want to exclude certain tables and you will need to replace the schema_name with the actual schema name. Clearly, you could put this in a function too, but it sounds like a one off exercise.

There may well be a simpler way that I am unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks John, perfect workaround with slight update.

```
DO $$Declare r record; 
  BEGIN 
    FOR r in SELECT srid as srs, f_table_name as name, f_geometry_column as geom
     FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_schema = 'Schema_name'
    LOOP
       RAISE NOTICE 'updating table: %, geom column: %, with srid: %', r.name, r.geom, r.srs;
       PERFORM UpdateGeometrySRID(quote_ident(r.name), quote_ident(r.geom), 2154); 
       EXECUTE FORMAT ('UPDATE %I set %I = ST_Transform(%I, 2154)', r.name, r.geom, r.geom);
   END LOOP;
END $$;
```