# Set SRID in all tables on a schema

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I have a lot of tables with column geom (Multipolygon) without SRID in PostgreSQL/PostGIS.

I need to set all tables  with a SRID of 3003.

This is my first time with SQL function.

I'm using a part of code of [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/303429/89395):

```
DO $$Declare r record; 
  BEGIN 
    FOR r in SELECT srid as srs, f_table_name as name, f_geometry_column as geom
     FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_schema = 'Schema_name'
    LOOP
       RAISE NOTICE 'updating table: %, geom column: %, with srid: %', r.name, r.geom, r.srs;
       PERFORM UpdateGeometrySRID(quote_ident(r.name), quote_ident(r.geom), 3003); 

   END LOOP;
END $$;
```

and the result is:

```
NOTIFICA:  updating table: pat4, geom column: geom, with srid: 0


ERRORE:  la funzione updategeometrysrid(name, name, integer) non esiste
LINE 1: SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID(r.name, r.geom, 3003)
               ^
HINT:  Nessuna funzione trovata con nome e tipi di argomenti forniti. Potrebbe essere necessario convertire i tipi esplicitamente.
QUERY:  SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID(r.name, r.geom, 3003)
CONTEXT:  funzione PL/pgSQL inline_code_block riga 7 a PERFORM
```

I don't understand because it doesn't recognise the function.

Comment: Please fix your URL reference

Comment: Sorry, now it goes

Comment: effectively without parentheses it works but It doesn't set the srid :"Query returned successfully with no result in 15 msec."

Comment: Transformed my comment into an answer; I also added my suspicion as to why it doesn't work...

Comment: Please don't paste a solution in the question. You can post your own Answer, but it breaks the Q&A model to post the answer in the Question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer: pass the **raw string** to the function!

`quote_ident` will format the input string into a **SQL *identifier***, effectively wrapping it in `"`; `UpdateGeometrySRID` however, accepts plain **`VARCHAR` strings**, and runs identifier checks internally!

---

**However:**

You may need to **specify the schema** in `UpdateGeometrySRID`:

```
DO $$
  DECLARE
    r record; 
  BEGIN 
    FOR r in (
      SELECT srid AS srs,
             f_table_name AS "name",
             f_table_schema AS "schema",
             f_geometry_column AS geom
      FROM   geometry_columns
      WHERE  f_table_schema = 'Schema_name'
    ) LOOP
       RAISE NOTICE 'updating table: %.%, geom column: %, with srid: %', r."schema", r."name", r.geom, r.srs;
       PERFORM UpdateGeometrySRID(r."schema", r."name", r.geom, 3003); 
    END LOOP;
  END;
$$
```

Without an explicit schema given, the function will call `current_schema()` to fill in, which **defaults to `public`**!

Comment: Perfect!!! I specified the scheme. Thank you very much. I add the solution in my post.

Comment: @DanielePiccolo ah scusi, I actually forgot to include what I proposed into the function I copied in ;-) it's updated now

Comment: nice - the rare Postgres DO block

Comment: This yielded a syntax error in my case with wrong argument types, it worked after using quote_ident around the UpdateGeometrySRID function, e.g.  ... `PERFORM UpdateGeometrySRID(quote_ident(r."name"), quote_ident(r."geom"), 25832); ` ...

Comment: @TimothyDalton well, that's exactly the opposite of what I proposed ,) do any of your tables have `"`-wrapped names? I may need to investigate...

Comment: @geozelot yea, it's a little curious.. here is one of the tables.. 
`psql (11.4 (Debian 11.4-1.pgdg100+1))
                                     Table "public.pointsofinterest"
  Column   |         Type         | Collation | Nullable |                    Default
-----------+----------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
 pid       | bigint               |           | not null | nextval('pointsofinterest_pid_seq'::regclass)
 osm_id    | bigint               |           |          |
 the_geom  | geometry(Point,4326) |           |          |`